# Folner sequence of $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$

Tags: abelian-groups, amenability

Consider $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ consisting of rational numbers of the form $k2^l$ with $k,l\in\mathbb{Z}$. Under addition and discrete topology $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ is a discrete abelian group, hence a countable discrete amenable group.

Question: Can we write down explicitly a Folner sequence of $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$?

Comment: I just learned about Følner sequences just now, but let $S_n$ be the set of numbers of the form $k2^l$ with $l\ge-n$. Doesn't $\{S_n\cap[-n,n]\}_{n=0}^\infty$ work?

Comment: It works. Thanks.